# Diff .sketch Files in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-diff, sketchapp

I need to diff our designer's files for the purpose of front-end development. I successfully implemented the following doc for diffing **.sketch** files with the git command-line:

https://gist.github.com/bomberstudios/c9e6975acd4d4d84a728

I would like to make sourcetree diff **.sketch** files as well but I can't seem to do it. Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use different diff tools? You can do it in `SourceTree > Preferences > Diff > External Diff / Merge` settings. I checked the approach in gist you referred. For me it works only after committing:
[image: Source Tree with .sketch file in commits]

But before committing I see only endless loading indicator. Maybe it will be enough for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Sketch 43** the file format structure changed, if you remove the *.sketch* file extension and replace it for a *.zip* you are able to decompress it's content and explore the document structure.

Here's more info: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-sketch-43-file-format-1f0ba31c3096

This **node.js** library relies on this new capability to convert **Sketch** files to **JSON** back and forth so you can use *Source Control* (Git/SVN) to review differences between files:

https://github.com/bukinoshita/sketch-json